# DBMS.XMLDOM : How to get node text value in xml

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Let's say I have this xml file :

```
<root>
  <id>2</id>
</root>

Code : 

myParser := DBMS_XMLPARSER.newParser;
ficContent := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.Read2Clob('MY_DIR', 'myfile.xml' , '0');
DBMS_XMLPARSER.parseBuffer(myParser,ficContent);
dom := DBMS_XMLPARSER.getDocument(myParser);
rootElement := DBMS_XMLDOM.getDocumentElement(dom);
nl := DBMS_XMLDOM.getChildrenByTagname(rootElement, 'id');
node := DBMS_XMLDOM.item(nl, 0); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Node name : ' || DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeName(node) || ' / value : ' || DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(node));
```

Result:

```
Node name : id
/ value : it is empty !!!!
```

So I have to problem to reach the node but cannot get the value

I think it must be obvious but...I dont see it. Should I call another method?

Ty

Comment: So now your `MY_DIR` .. has worked. You should not had deleted that answer coz I had mentioned important exception handling clause in that

Comment: I was not pointing to the right place...Stupid mistake, so the post had no point. Can u answer this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it was obvious :

I should write:

```
DBMS_XMLDOM.getNodeValue(DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(node));
```

Comment: if nobody can answer it and I find the answer, I share. What is wrong with you, you did not have your points ? Live with that.